# What way should i use to separate regular users's from admin users's layouts in an Angular application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt

I have just been informed about the new project i'm going to work on , basically it an administrative  application  that involves many users with different roles and permissions to manage .
and for the moment i'm considering 2 options to create the different layouts we will need .

## 1. Create for each user a Lazy loaded module contains all the layout components related to the specific role of that user, with the use of a shared module contains shared components , services ...etc.

## 2. Using one layout module that contains the whole layout , and control the rendering of UI using conditions.

if anyone has ever worked on such application with many kind of users, i would be thankful for provide any information on how to design this kind of apps.
thank you

Comment: 2nd one is a best approach, you can conditionally show/hide elements based on user roles and also you can protect entire page with routing guard. To show/hide create a custom `ngIf` to validate user roles and implement a routing guard

Comment: Yes, it seems doable, but I'm worried about that there's too much configuration and management panels related to each user role, isn't that going to make the code a bit messy as the application grows?

Comment: I would suggest you to look into [jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/), Jhipster created a common structural directive **(*jhiHasAnyAuthority)** to show/hide elements based on roles, and you can create a common **canActivate** service. This is a one time configuration.

Comment: thank you very much jhipster looks very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is better & scalable

Create for each user a Lazy loaded module contains all the layout components related to the specific role of that user, with the use of a shared module contains shared components , services ...etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , have you worked on such application using the same pattern ?

Comment: Yes. I have worked on same pattern for multiple hierarchical user

Comment: thank you very much , we have already started building using this pattern .

Answer (score 0):

Our projects use routers and directives to control permission based visibility and access. If you only have two roles you can separate the modules but once you get into a more complex permission structure you will need this to occur with directives within a single component.

For example, User A with Role A with specific READ/WRITE/NONE permissions on various tables or data.

You can build directives that can handle user types and permissions. Here is an example usage where the user can only see this div if they are an Admin and have the correct authorities:

```
      <div *restricted="''; 
            hasLoginType: LoginType.ADMIN; 
            hasAuthority: [Authorities.TASK_MANAGEMENT_VIEW_ALL, Authorities.MIGRATION_VIEW_ALL]">
```

Your implementation could be much simpler.

Comment: thank you very much the application is indeed a bit complex, with many permissions and roles to handle , i think we are going this way